# Junit -- Command line argument

Tags: java, junit, program-entry-point

I have just started learning JUnit. I have code as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
  private void verify(args) {...}
  private void process(clientoptions) {...}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    verify(args);
    //get client and do something
    .....
    // some more code here....
    ........
    // and then 
    process(clientoptions);
  }
}
```

How do you write a test in Junit and then send in different command line arguments.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Simple!

```
public class MyClassTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldVerifyParameters() {
        MyClass.main(new String[]{"param1", "param2"});
    }

}
```

However for ease of testing consider refactoring `MyClass` into `MyClassMain` and `MyClass` where the former only parses and verifies command line arguments and calls the latter class with `clientoptions`.

This way you don't violate [*Single responsibility principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and you can use the business logic outside of `main`, for instance in servlet or on a mobile. Also... testing is simpler.

Comment: If process(clientoptions) returns a boolean value inidcating error status then how can I use assertTrue method to check the result. The main method returns void. Thanks.

Comment: First of all if you go with the refactoring I suggested you can test `process()` directly. Secondly return `false` to indicate an error is a bad design, use exceptions instead.